# Giving an @Option annotation a default setting, java

Tags: java, command-line, annotations, args4j

```
@Option(name = "-readFromFolder",usage = "specifies a folder containing files to read")
    private String folderName;
```

The way it works now is that the user has specifies the folder `-readFromFolder=/home`

I want them to be able to say `-readFromFolder` and set a default for which to look into, like ${user.home}

Something that works like this, but I ca't figure out the syntax

```
@Option(name = "-readFromFolder",usage = "specifies a folder containing files to read")
        private String folderName (default=${user.home});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/) library - it does not support default parameter values. You have to implement it yourself:

```
private final static String DEFAULT_FOLDER_NAME = "${user.home}";
@Option(name = "-readFromFolder",usage = "specifies a folder containing files to read")
private String folderName;

public String getFolderName() {
    return null == folderName ? DEFAULT_FOLDER_NAME : folderName ;
}
```

Comment: can we not set the default value in the member variable declaration instead?

Comment: above works for me. putting an example as answer

Answer (score 1):

it is feasible to set the default value in the member variable declaration itself instead

```
@Option(name = "-o", aliases = "--output", usage = "Fully qualified path and name of output JSON file.", required = false)
private String output = "./examples/sample.json"
```

tested this from command line. seems to work as expected.

Comment: This makes more sense. You can also see it is intended to be used that way, as args4j will automatically document the default value in `CmdLineParser.printUsage()`, as for example in "Number of requests to perform per action type (default: 10)".